# Is it known the value of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{ n^2}$?

Tags: calculus, summation, information-theory

In my information theory course, we have been asked to find the entropy of a particular distribution in $\mathbb{N}$. In order to do so, I have come to the following integral
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor }{2^{2\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor}}$$
I would be content approximating it by $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\log_2(n)}{ n^2}$, but I don't know how to compute it neither (or if this is even possible).

I know that the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\log(n)}{ n^2}$ (with the natural logarithm for example), converges (Bertrand series), but I would like to know if its value is known.

I apologize if this has already been answered, or if it is easy to find somewhere else.

Comment: It's $-\zeta'(2)$, if that satisfies you.

Comment: ... and $\zeta'(2)$ you will get with the first derivation of $\zeta(1-s)=\frac{2}{(2\pi)^s}\cos\frac{\pi s}{2}\Gamma(s)\zeta(s)$ at $s=2$ and $\zeta'(-1)=\frac{1}{2}-\ln A$ where $A$ is called the Glaisher-Kinkelin constant, e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%E2%80%93Kinkelin_constant). But it's better you look at the answer of *GEdgar*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the integer part still in there
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor }{2^{2\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor}}
$$
proceed like this.

For $n=1$ we have $\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor = 0$.

For $2 \le n < 4$ we have $\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor = 1.\qquad$  (two terms)

For $4 \le n < 8$ we have $\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor = 2.\qquad$   (four terms)

And so on,

For $2^k \le n < 2^{k+1}$ we have $\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor = k.\qquad$   ($2^k$ terms)

So
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor }{2^{2\lfloor \log_2n \rfloor}} =
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^k\;\frac{k}{2^{2k}} = 2
$$

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful, much simpler than expected. Thank you!